# Back button to two different JSPs

Tags: jsp, back-button

I had two JSP pages, say page A and page C.

Clicking on a particular hyperlink on A causes C to load. There is a back button on C which always goes back to page A.
Also, now I added another page B and when a particular link is clicked on it, page C loads again.

Now, if I click the "back" button, it still goes back to page A. How can I make the back button function in a way that it takes me back to the calling JSP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Accept answers for the questions you have asked

Comment: I just did that.. How does it actually matter?

Comment: Thank you. I shall verify your answer and then accept it if it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not hard code the back button link in page C. Instead, send the caller page as a parameter to the page C. And set that parameter in the back button link.

**Here is how the pages look like:**

Page A

```
<a href="pagec.jsp?caller=pagea.jsp">Page C</a>
```

Page B

```
<a href="pagec.jsp?caller=pageb.jsp">Page C</a>
```

Page C

```
<a href="${param.caller}">Back</a>
```